# Pre-Release binary information in iTunesConnect is empty

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I try to upload my Mac App to the App Store, but I am in trouble with iTunesConnect since one week by now. I definitely need your kind help.

I read the Apple documentation a couple of times and asked google for a  solution. I tried new Certificates and provision Profiles, a lot of build settings and - yes - I even moved to a new mac with a fresh Xcode on it. No success so far.

Here is my story: I build and run my app successfully. I subscribed to the Mac Developer Program and configured my project to sign the application for a App Store submission.

[image: Project settings]

I made an archive and validated it successfully.

[image: Validator settings] 
[image: Validator results]

Then I exported the Binary like the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html) suggested and all tests passed.
[image: Installer test]

Then I uploaded the archive to iTunesConnect. The archive got processed and then... I got the little triangle near the build and as I clicked onto that build, there is absolutely no information all.

[image: Triangle indicator]

[image: Build Information]
*Sorry I moved to a german Mac and didn't change the language to English by now*

After nine builds and one week of reading and trying I have absolutely no idea how to solve that problem.

Thank you very much for every new thought.

*** UPDATE ***

I removed the provision profile and created a new one. Then I built a complete new Project with the same ID and uploaded it as a new build number. Again, the pre-release tab is empty.
[image: Provision Profile]
[image]
These are my code signing settings:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem on a new version of an iOS app (so it's already on the store). I hope it's only a temporary problem or delay on Apple's side. I can also submit again and again, which shouldn't be possible otherwise.

Comment: Using Application Loader instead of Xcode did the trick for me.

Comment: I don't have this luck.

Comment: I released the empty binary to the review process. We will see what happens.